# How to debug a 404 error when using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here is the Controller class:

```
    package me.ankit.zooplus;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class HomeController {   
        @RequestMapping("/home")
        public String home() {

        return "home";
    }
}
```

and this is my application class

```
package me.ankit.zooplus;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ZooplusApplication  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ZooplusApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

My folder structure is as follows:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4dlF.jpg)

I have this from maven [copy and pasted few lines from the console]:

```
INFO 7484 --- [lication.main()] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/home]}" onto public java.lang.String me.ankit.zooplus.HomeController.home()
INFO 7484 --- [lication.main()] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
INFO 7484 --- [lication.main()] me.ankit.zooplus.ZooplusApplication      : Started ZooplusApplication in 10.554 seconds (JVM running for 16.948)

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

and Finally my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>me.ankit</groupId>
<artifactId>zooplus</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>zooplus</name>
<description>zooplus: Currency Converter</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hot swapping, disable cache for template, enable live reload -->       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

What could have been gone wrong ?
Also is there a place/view/log, I can go in future to check what is wrong ?

Comment: I have hosted my source code at github here: https://github.com/shortduck/spring-boot-thymeleaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cloned your project and ran it. I do have couple of notes:

1. In your `pom.xml`, you have added `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency, which will create a default login page once you access your web application. If you don't need security at this stage remove all security dependencies from your `pom.xml` or you have to provide Security Configuration for your application.
2. When accessing your application, make sure you add "home" to your URL: http://localhost:8080/home because this is mapped to your controller. If you want to add a default context to your application add the following to *application.properties*: `server.servlet.contextPath=/zooplus`, then you can access it through the URL: http://localhost:8080/zooplus/home

Comment: Thanks Luay, 
1. I entered the password by looking at the console.
2.I was also executing the app using incorrect command, I had used `mnvw string-boot:start`, it compiled the code, starts Tomcat and shuts it down at the same time. So I did the following which helped me keep going: 1. `mvn package` 2. `java -jar myapplication.jar` .